# HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type while processing JSON

Tags: java, json, gradle, jersey, javabeans

My code is working with Xml but fails with Json

Request with RestEasy UI:

```
POST /api/people HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:application/json

{
    "name":"developer",
    "age":"25",
    "address":"address"
}
```

**Class Resource.java**

```
package people;

@Path("/api")
public class Resource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("helloworld")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("people")
    public String updatePeople(People request)  { 
        People p = new People();
        p.setName(request.getName());

        return p.getName(); 
    }
}
```

**and class People.java**

```
package people;

@XmlRootElement
public class People {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: Define: `fails with Json`

Comment: What is RestEasy UI? I am assuming this means that you are using RESTEasy and not Jersey (or no)? Please clarify. And is there any exception on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

add default constructor in bean class People.

```
 public people(){
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following jar to your class path. 
   **jersey-media-json-jackson.jar**

If you are using Maven, add this to your POM.xml file.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are facing the following exception on the server side:

> javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find
>   message body reader for type: class people.People of
>   content type: application/json

**In this case you need to add the `resteasy-jackson2-provider` dependency to your project**; so, assuming that you are using Maven, try putting this into your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```